The probable error of a mean- seminal 1908 paper from Gosset (Student). Please help me to understand the second identity in Section 1
I am reading Student's t distribution original paper (1908), and in Section I, it mentioned the equation
$$\bar{s}^2=\frac{n\mu_2}{n}-\frac{n\mu_2}{n^2}=\frac{\mu_2(n-1)}{n}$$
and "... since $x_1,x_2$, etc., are not correlated and the distribution is normal, products involving odd powers of $x_1$ vanish on summing, so that $\frac{2S(x_1,x_2)}{n^2}$ is equal to $0$".
I am a bit confusing why $\frac{2S(x_1,x_2)}{n^2}$ can sum to $0$ without the assumption that the population mean is zero. Can somebody help me with this?

I found a quote in Section II of the paper "Clearly the positive and negative positions of the mean of the sample are equally likely...". So it somehow indicates that the so-called "normal distribution" has zero mean? Actually the way Gosset derived his Section II implicitly means that the distribution has zero mean
